# How to change font size of dropdown list of combobox in extjs4.1.0

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a form panel with one combobox, what i want is to change the style of dropdown list of combobox. I dnt want to use listCls so that i need to specify that cls where ever i use combobox. I want to override any general class so that with out mentioning listCls i can achive this??
for Example i have some 3 to 4 combo box in a single form panel . What i want is to change the dropdown list font style . Is there any general cls (like .x-form-combo-list) so that i can use that .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **x-boundlist-item** or **x-boundlist-list-ct**

Answer (score 0):

The correct class for specifically what you want is: **x-combo-list**.  There are many other classes associated with the items in the combobox dropdown, but this is the specific one that the font-family is defined in that is used for the display.